# JQuery Select2 - How to select all options

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using jQuery select2 multi select dropdown. I need to select all options in a dropdown from code.
Basically there is a Select All checkbox on which this functionality has to be implemented, I want to select/deselect options from this checkbox.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a description in thread on github. Quoting (https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/195#issuecomment-13489140 by [MortadaAK](https://github.com/MortadaAK)) which allows you to select everything on ctrl+a

```
$(document).on("keypress",".select2-input",function(event){
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
        var id =$(this).parents("div[class*='select2-container']").attr("id").replace("s2id_","");
        var element =$("#"+id);
        if (event.which == 97){
            var selected = [];
            element.find("option").each(function(i,e){
                selected[selected.length]=$(e).attr("value");
            });
            element.select2("val", selected);
        } else if (event.which == 100){
            element.select2("val", "");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @kkudi ask author on github

Comment: what am i meant to ask the author? the above code doesn't work for me at all. not sure why. i've done debugging of the code as well. my data is loaded via ajax though, not sure if there's any difference.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the behaviour I'm asking. What I want is once you type "be", a list of "bed", "bee", "bent", "bell" appears, and you want to select all elements from the list.

Comment: @kkudi you can still do it with Select All checkbox, but as Garath said you will have to write your own logic behind it. When the user types "be" and clicks Select All then mark all those values selected that start with "be".

Comment: If you're using underscore/lodash, you could programmatically select all options from your dropdown with something like:

`$("#someId").val(_.pluck($("#someId option"), "value")).trigger("change");`

Comment: Please note, that this code does not work when the results were loaded by ajax.

Answer (score 79):

using Select 2 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/62/)**

```
$("#e1").select2();
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
        $("#e1 > option").prop("selected","selected");// Select All Options
        $("#e1").trigger("change");// Trigger change to select 2
    }else{
        $("#e1 > option").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#e1").trigger("change");// Trigger change to select 2
     }
});

$("#button").click(function(){
       alert($("#e1").val());
});
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All

<input type="button" id="button" value="check Selected">
```

You need code As shown in **[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Gb77v/)** for Simple Select

```
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
        $("select > option").prop("selected","selected");
    }else{
        $("select > option").removeAttr("selected");
     }
});

$("#button").click(function(){
       alert($("select").val());
});

<select multiple size=2>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All

<input type="button" id="button" value="check Selected">
```

Comment: worked like a charm. I would only filter out options without values, or you will get blank options.  `$("#e1 > option").filter(function() { return $(this).val().length;  });`

Comment: what if I remove some of the option the select box is still selected how can make them select if I change some of the options.

Comment: DEOMO1: How to modify this to make it select only the options after doing the search function? For example you search for "ala" which brings Alabama and Amalapuram and then I want select all to select only these 2?

Comment: In firefox 114 the removal of selected options must be: `$("select > option").prop("selected","");`

Answer (score 37):

Answer from [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/195#issuecomment-22770367) works pretty good.

```
// Select all
$('#select-id').select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2();

// Unselect all
$('#select-id').select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', false).end().select2();
```

Comment: super simple way to load and unload options for select2. Thnx

Comment: Very neat & clean approach.

Comment: Is there any way to trigger change with this.

Answer (score 16):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-select").select2();
});

function selectAll() {
    $("#my-select > option").prop("selected", true);
    $("#my-select").trigger("change");
}

function deselectAll() {
    $("#my-select > option").prop("selected", false);
    $("#my-select").trigger("change");
}
```

```css
.button-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#my-select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="button-container">
  <button type="button" onclick="selectAll()">Select All</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="deselectAll()">Deselect All</button>
</div>
<select id="my-select" multiple>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="grape">Grape</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
</select>
```

This is the most simple way

```
function selectAll() {
  $("#my-select > option").prop("selected", true);
  $("#my-select").trigger("change"); 
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkbox").click(function(){
      if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){ //select all
        $("#e1").find('option').prop("selected",true);
        $("#e1").trigger('change');
      } else { //deselect all
        $("#e1").find('option').prop("selected",false);
        $("#e1").trigger('change');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>     //AJAX created
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>  //AJAX created
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>  //AJAX created
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option> //AJAX created
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>     //AJAX created
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All
```

If options are created after AJAX request then these options don't work. So we map them with find and select/unselect them , after that trigger change.

HTML

```
 <select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>     //AJAX created
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>  //AJAX created
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>  //AJAX created
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option> //AJAX created
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>     //AJAX created
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkbox").click(function(){
      if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){ //select all
        $("#e1").find('option').prop("selected",true);
        $("#e1").trigger('change');
      } else { //deselect all
        $("#e1").find('option').prop("selected",false);
        $("#e1").trigger('change');
      }
  });
});
```

just use find.

Answer (score 11):

you could do it for one string

```
$('select.your-select option').attr('selected', true).parent().trigger('change')
```

Comment: Very short option!

Comment: While this initially appears to work, the plugin doesn't seem to play nicely with it and will end up not selecting things that have been manually deselected.

Answer (score 7):

```js
$('.select2').select2({
  placeholder: 'Press CTRL+A for select or unselect all options'
});

$('.select2[multiple]').siblings('.select2-container').append('<span class="select-all"></span>');

$(document).on('click', '.select-all', function (e) {
  selectAllSelect2($(this).siblings('.selection').find('.select2-search__field'));
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".select2-search__field", function (e) {
  var eventObj = window.event ? event : e;
  if (eventObj.keyCode === 65 && eventObj.ctrlKey)
     selectAllSelect2($(this));
});
        
        
function selectAllSelect2(that) {

  var selectAll = true;
  var existUnselected = false;
  var item = $(that.parents("span[class*='select2-container']").siblings('select[multiple]'));

  item.find("option").each(function (k, v) {
      if (!$(v).prop('selected')) {
          existUnselected = true;
          return false;
      }
  });

  selectAll = existUnselected ? selectAll : !selectAll;

  item.find("option").prop('selected', selectAll);
  item.trigger('change');
}
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 90% !important;
}

.select2-container .select-all {
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        right: 4px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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') no-repeat center;
        background-size: contain;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="select2" multiple id="my-select">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is this global for all select2 or do we need it separately for each select2 field?

Comment: This is global for all select2 fields with class .select2 (in my case). You can specify an additional class or attribute to implement this functionality only for a limited amount of fields.

Comment: thanks, @MihaiCiobanu I have tried it, and working perfectly, it's the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Info: The values for gSiteIDs are the values used when originally dynamically creating the select options. #selAllSites is the id of a checkbox and #siteID is the id of the select list you want to manipulate.

```
var gSiteIDs = "8475, 9082, 2387, 1234";

function selectAllSites() 
{
    if($("#selAllSites").is(":Checked")) {
        $("#siteID").select2("val", [gSiteIDs]);                                
    } else {
        $("#siteID").select2("val", []);                                
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've found for this, other answers put you in a state that has potential to get really glitchy.

Comment: Yes please. Everything else potentially corrupts the select2 itself. You could choose to get the values from the element itself i.e: var values = $.map($select2.find('option') ,function(option) { return option.value; });

Answer (score 1):

[@Garath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16538539/282110): I have tweaked your posted code in order to make it work with results that are loaded via ajax. Thank you for bringing this up here.

```
    $(document).on("keypress",".select2-input",function(event){
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
        var id =$(this).parents("div[class*='select2-container']").attr("id").replace("s2id_","");
        var element =$("#"+id);
        if (event.which == 97){
            var selected = [];
            $('.select2-drop-active').find("ul.select2-results li").each(function(i,e){
                selected.push($(e).data("select2-data"));
            });
            element.select2("data", selected);
        } else if (event.which == 100){
            element.select2("data", []);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Jim is there a select all with mouse click?

Answer (score 1):

Custom implementation of Select all in select2 [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yikekas/w8edmLqy/68/)

```js
function RunSelect2(){
  $('#select-id').select2({
     allowClear: true,
     closeOnSelect: false,
  }).on('select2:open', function() {  

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".select2-results__option .select2-results__group").bind( "click", selectAlllickHandler ); 
    }, 0);

  });
}

RunSelect2();


var selectAlllickHandler = function() {
 $(".select2-results__option .select2-results__group").unbind( "click", selectAlllickHandler );        
  $('#select-id').select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end();
  RunSelect2();
};
```

```css
.select2-results__group
{
  cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select multiple id='select-id' style="width:300px">
    <optgroup label="select all">
      <option value='1'>1 one</option>
      <option value='2'>2 two</option>
      <option value='3'>3 three</option>
      <option value='4'>4 four</option>
      <option value='5'>5 five</option>
      <option value='6'>6 six</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2019**

To programmatically select an option/item for a Select2 control, use the jQuery `.val()` method.

You can also pass an array to `val` make multiple selections:

```
$('#mySelect2').val(['1', '2']);
$('#mySelect2').trigger('change');
```

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

Answer (score 1):

Please see below code.

```
$('.select2').select2({
    formatResult:function(object, container, query){
        if(object.id=='all' || object.id=='clear')
            return '<span style="color:#31708F;font-size:10px;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> '+object.text+'</span>';

        return object.text;
    }
});
$('.select2').on("change", function(e) {
    if($.inArray('all', e.val)===0){
        var selected = [];
        $(this).find("option").each(function(i,e){
            if($(e).attr("value")=='all' || $(e).attr("value")=='clear')
                return true;

            selected[selected.length]=$(e).attr("value");
        });
        $(this).select2('val',selected);
    }else if($.inArray('clear', e.val)===0){
        $(this).select2('val','');
    }
});
```

Reference from: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/195#issuecomment-52163095

Answer (score 0):

This works great with AJAX, prevents from opening Bookmarks window in FF (Ctrl-D), and works fine when closeOnSelect is set to off.

```
$(document).on("keypress",".select2-input",function(event){
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
        var id =$(this).parents("div[class*='select2-container']").attr("id").replace("s2id_","");
        var element =$("#"+id);

        if (event.which == 97){
            var selected = [];
            $('.select2-drop-active').find("ul.select2-results li").each(function(i,e){
                selected.push($(e).data("select2-data"));
            });
            element.select2("data", selected);
            element.select2("focus");
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event.which == 100){
            element.select2("data", []);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require([
    'select2/utils',
    'select2/dropdown',
    'select2/dropdown/attachBody'
], function (Utils, Dropdown, AttachBody) {
    function SelectAll() { }

    SelectAll.prototype.render = function (decorated) {
        var $rendered = decorated.call(this);
        var self = this;

        var $selectAll = $(
            '<button type="button" style="width: 100%; height: 3rem; text-align: left; color: blue; background: none; border: none; box-shadow: none">Select All</button>'
        );

        $rendered.find('.select2-dropdown').prepend($selectAll);

        $selectAll.on('click', function (e) {
            var $results = $rendered.find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]');

            // Get all results that aren't selected
            $results.each(function () {
                var $result = $(this);

                // Get the data object for it
                var data = $result.data('data');

                // Trigger the select event
                self.trigger('select', {
                    data: data
                });
            });

            self.trigger('close');
        });

        return $rendered;
    };

    $("#select-id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select weekdays...",
        allowClear: true,
        dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(
            Utils.Decorate(
                Dropdown,
                AttachBody
            ),
            SelectAll
        )
    });
});
```

Source code: http://jsbin.com/seqonozasu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: If you manually select 2 items in the list, and then 'Select All', it will select everything except the 2 items you originally selected.

Answer (score 0):

just look this jsFiddle i created , sure this is the answer all you searched

[Select2 Multiple dropdown with select all property](https://jsfiddle.net/shabeen/20fuo6bx/13)

```js
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
    if($(".checkbox").is(':checked') ){
        $(this).parent().find('option').prop("selected","selected");
        $(this).parent().find('option').trigger("change");
        $(this).parent().find('option').click();
        
    }else{
       $(this).parent().find('option').removeAttr("selected","selected");
       $(this).parent().find('option').trigger("change");
     }
});

$("#button").click(function(){
       alert($("select").val());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2').select2({
           closeOnSelect: false,
           allowClear:false
        });
        });
```

```html
<div>
<select multiple size=2 class="select2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" >Select All
</div>

<div>
<select multiple size=2 class="select2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" >Select All
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a checkbox for this action, just do this simply.

```
<select id="myselect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
  <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
  <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
  <option value="level4">Level 4</option>
</select>

<br/>
Select/Deselect <input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>
```

Jquery function:

```
$("#selectall").on('click',function(){
    var checked = $("#selectall").prop("checked");
  if(checked==true){
    $("#myselect > option").prop("selected",true);
  }else{
    $("#myselect > option").prop("selected",false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$result.data('data');
```

to

```
Utils.GetData($result.get(0),'data')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will select all options

```
$('select.select-all-class-name').attr('selected', true).parent().trigger('change');
```

Add select events to work for all scenarios. The above line fails in a scenario, when you select and deselect an option and then click on selectAll. The last deselected option will not get selected. In order to fix that Add the below line of code.

```
//Select options selected true for the selected option
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
    $('select#mySelect2ID > option[value="'+e.params.args.data.id+'"]').attr('selected', true);
});

//DeSelect options selected to false for the option deselected
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
    $('select#mySelect2ID > option[value="'+e.params.args.data.id+'"]').attr('selected', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The select2 only needs to closed and opened again to update its selected values. No need to destroy it.

```
$('#select-id').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected');

if ($('#select-id').data('select2').isOpen()) {
    $('#select-id').select2('close').select2('open');
}
```

Comment: Instead of the entire `if` statement you should be able to do `$('#select-id').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0):

Select2: Select All Options & Deselect All options using click event

Using Select2: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kaamrul/xmf3agzc/1/)

```js
$('#category_id').select2({
  placeholder: "Select Category",
  allowClear: false,
  multiple: true, // Search
});
$('#category_id').siblings('.select2-container').append('<span class="select-all"><i class="fa-regular fa-square-check"></i></span>');
    
$(document).on('click', '.select-all', function (e) {
  selectAllSelect2($(this).siblings('.selection').find('.select2-search__field'));
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".select2-search__field", function (e) {
  var eventObj = window.event ? event : e;
  if (eventObj.keyCode === 65 && eventObj.ctrlKey)
    selectAllSelect2($(this));
});

function selectAllSelect2(that) {

  var selectAll = true;
  var existUnselected = false;
  var item = $(that.parents("span[class*='select2-container']").siblings('select[multiple]'));

  item.find("option").each(function (k, v) {
    if (!$(v).prop('selected')) {
      existUnselected = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  selectAll = existUnselected ? selectAll : !selectAll;

  item.find("option").prop('selected', selectAll);
  item.trigger('change');
}
```

```css
.select2-container .select-all {
    z-index: 3;
    color: #46c484;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 0.35rem;
    right: 0.65rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<!-- Select2 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<!-- Select2 JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div style="padding:30px;">
  <select class="form-control" multiple id="category_id" style="width:300px">
    <option value="1">Category A</option>
    <option value="2">Category B</option>
    <option value="3">Category C</option>
    <option value="4">Category D</option>
    <option value="5">Category E</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This Code Work for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
  if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){ //select all
    $("#e1").find('option').prop("selected",true);
    $("#e1").trigger('change');
  } else { //deselect all
    $("#e1").val(null).trigger('change');
  }
```

});
});