# How to implement select all functionality with select2 jquery plugin configured with ajax search.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Iam currently using select2 jquery plugin to select data from list dynamically populated from an ajax call. I need to implement select all functionality so that users are able to select all the options at once by using a select all button. I have tried to implement this following this example in jsfidde.

[Click here to see the jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/jecunizoja/edit?html,js,output)

But for selecting a listing of larger number of items say 500 items.It makes the browser hang for a while. Please suggest a better way to implement this without any performance issues.

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require([
 'select2/utils',
 'select2/dropdown',
 'select2/dropdown/attachBody'
 ], function (Utils, Dropdown, AttachBody) {
 function SelectAll() { }

SelectAll.prototype.render = function (decorated) {
var $rendered = decorated.call(this);
var self = this;

var $selectAll = $(
  '<button type="button">Select All</button>'
);

$rendered.find('.select2-dropdown').prepend($selectAll);

$selectAll.on('click', function (e) {
  var $results = $rendered.find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]');

  // Get all results that aren't selected
  $results.each(function () {
    var $result = $(this);

    // Get the data object for it
    var data = $result.data('data');

    // Trigger the select event
    self.trigger('select', {
      data: data
    });
  });

  self.trigger('close');
});

return $rendered;
```

};

```
 $("select").select2({
placeholder: "Select Option(s)...",
dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(
  Utils.Decorate(
    Dropdown,
    AttachBody
  ),
  SelectAll
  ),
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the duplicate question of
[JQuery Select2 - How to select all options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538399/jquery-select2-how-to-select-all-options)

where solution given for multiple select with checkbox.

if its getting load than you should add extra hidden filed to get comma separated value.

try below code.
HTML :

```
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All
<br>
<input type="text" id="valueall" value="" name="valueall">
```

JQuery :

```
$("#e1").select2();
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
        $("#e1 > option").prop("selected","selected");
        <!-- $("#e1").trigger("change"); -->
        $("#e1").select2('destroy'); 
        $("#e1").hide(); 
        $("#valueall").val($("#e1").val())
    }else{
        $("#e1 > option").removeAttr("selected");
         <!-- $("#e1").trigger("change"); -->
         $("#e1").select2(); 
        $("#e1").show(); 
         $("#valueall").val($("#e1").val())
     }
});
```

You can set type="hidden" for input field.

Comment: Yes, But he is saying its working fine but this makes browser hangs when we select more den 500 items.

Comment: @Parth No, I need to make sure the browser doesn't hang on selecting lots of elements with select all

Comment: @albert for that you also can put one checkbox for select all, on that make select disable and fetch all values in hidden field with comma separate.

Comment: @Parth Could you please provide a working jsfiddle for this implementation. ?

Comment: @albert i have added sample code. you can try this.