# Select2 with "all" option (ajax query)

Tags: jquery, ajax, webforms, jquery-select2

I have a listbox :

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxCodeProduct"
    [...]
    CssClass="SelectProducts select2-selected-options"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
```

My select2 use ajax to get data in ListBox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.SelectProducts').select2({
        placeholder: 'Choose product(s)',
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "../Product.ashx",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                [...]
                };
                return params;
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                [...]
                };
            },
            cache: false
        },
        minimumInputLength: 0
    });
});
```

I would like an option "all products" (with a checkbox for exemple) inside my listbox to allow all options.

I found many solutions, but always with data in html (with "li" and "option" but never with ajax)
I would like to do something like this :

```
$("#CheckBoxAllProducts").click(function(){
    if($("#CheckBoxAllProducts").is(':checked') ){
        $(".SelectProducts'> li").prop("selected","selected");
        $(".SelectProducts'").trigger("change");
    }else{
        $(".SelectProducts'> li").removeAttr("selected");
        $(".SelectProducts'").trigger("change");
    }
});
```

How I do it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact the data comes from AJAX should make no difference. Try this answer from a previous similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543623/519413

Comment: When you click `#CheckBoxAllProducts` the elements will be present in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Thank your for your answer, I already saw this topic. But Yes it's different, because my DOM doesn't contain my result list.

But somebody help me:
(we start to declare my product list during click on checkBox)

```
 $("#CheckBoxAllProducts").click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Product.ashx",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { taillePage: 100 },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            var select2 = $('.SelectProducts'),
                selectedValues = [];
            select2.empty();
            $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                select2.append($('<option>', {
                    value: item.id,
                    text: item.text
                }));
                selectedValues.push(item.id);
            });
            select2.val(selectedValues).trigger('change');
        });
    });
```

And it's working now! :) 
Thank you