# How can I select all the options in a multi select form laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Data is fetching from the database, I want to select all locations coming from the database by default

```
 @php
          $default_location = null;
          if(count($business_locations) == 1){
            $default_location = array_key_first($business_locations->toArray());
          }
        @endphp
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('product_locations', __('business.business_locations') . ':') !!} @show_tooltip(__('lang_v1.product_location_help'))
              {!! Form::select('product_locations[]', $business_locations, $default_location, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple', 'id' => 'product_locations']); !!}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `{!! Form::select('product_locations[]', $business_locations, $default_location, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple', 'id' => 'product_locations'], 'selected' => 'true'); !!}` I think it works for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// all selected
$("#product_locations").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: For more info checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538399/jquery-select2-how-to-select-all-options